# Resources to learn XNA for a professional c# developer

Tags: xna, c#, assets

I'm a .net consultant (mainly c#) for my job, but for a while now, I've been interested in making a game in XNA (as a hobby project).

I've had a "beginner" course in XNA when I was still a student, but I've lost most of the information (plus, it was VERY beginner, not enough to get you really started).

So my question, which resources would be useful for me to learn XNA (books, blogs, websites, tutorials, resource websites - like textures, audio files, etc..)?

I know this is a very open question, but I'm thankful for any information.

Comment: "How do I get started?" questions are not good questions to ask here as defined in the [FAQ](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/faq). You could try asking chat or [GameDev.net](http://www.gamedev.net/)

Comment: [Shameless](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/users/288/andrew-russell?tab=answers&sort=votes) [self-promotion](http://stackoverflow.com/users/165500/andrew-russell?tab=answers&sort=votes) ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was in the same situation as you in the sense that I was already very familiar with C# and .NET and just wanted to learn the XNA API as quickly as possible. I'll just describe the resources I've used in the beginning.

In that situation (and although it's a bit outdated now because the API changed a bit in version 4.0) I found [Riemers (check his website too)](http://www.riemers.net/) book "**XNA 3.0 Game Programming Recipes A Problem-Solution Approach**" to be really useful:

[image]

The reason for that is that the book is divided into small sections, or *recipes*, about 3 or 4 pages each, and each recipe is focused on a different problem, a different portion of the API. At the start of the book he also recommends many different orders to read the book depending on your goals.

So I read through the recommended recipes to get up to speed with 2D and 3D rendering, content loading and input handling, which took less than a day, and afterwards, any time I picked the book I would just look at the table of contents, pick a recipe that interested me at random and read it.

But what I was particularly surprised with was the breadth of topics covered, because after all of the basic beginner recipes, there are also a lot of recipes on advanced topics that I really didn't expect to see in the same book, such as:

- vertex and pixel shaders
- ocean shader (complete with waves, refraction, reflection, and fresnel term)
- particle system
- bloom post processing
- shadow mapping
- bump mapping
- a procedural race track with catmull-rom
- height-map terrain
- octree
- deferred shading
- picking

Comment: Woaw, this book seems great for me! Thanks for the advice

Comment: @Team-JoKi The only problem is that version 4.0 of XNA was released since then and there were a few breaking changes in the API. But it should be simple enough to work with it, and when something does not work, check [this list](http://nelxon.com/resources/xna-3-1-to-xna-4-0-cheatsheet.php) to see if there was any change.

Comment: I would not recommend that book. The 4.0 API made quite a few breaking changes (for the better) especially shader related things . There are plenty XNA4 books out there http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_ss_i_3_3?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=xna+4.0&sprefix=XNA%2Caps%2C360 one of them is bound to be good :). Edit: sounded a bit harsh, I would totally recommend it if you were going to use XNA3 :)

Comment: While I do own this book, I wouldn't recommend it.  It's out-dated, and even then I didn't find it very useful to a complete XNA beginner.

Comment: @RoyT. I've read a few other of those books, and although it varies from book to book, my experience with most of them is that they spend the entire book teaching only the basics at an excruciatingly slow pace for someone with programming experience, and end before getting to the interesting parts. It is for the pace  and scope of the book that I recommended it, benefits which for me were more relevant than making the changes to XNA 4.0.

Comment: @Cypher I guess it depends on the definition XNA beginner. I was a XNA beginner in a sense that I had never used it before, but I already had a solid programming foundation, knew C# and .NET, and had already played around with making games before (e.g. in Mode13h with Pascal, Visual Basic, OpenGL and DirectX 8 and 9). What I needed was a book that got me up to speed quickly with this new technology, and the book delivered it in a couple of days. Since the title of the topic says "XNA for professional c# developer" I assumed a certain level of proficiency when making the recommendation.

Comment: @David Gouveia, I was in the same boat with a similar background and the book just confused me even more. I found it more useful once I finally understood enough about XNA to build something, but for some reason I just didn't find it all that helpful to learn the API. I suppose we all learn in different ways. :)

Comment: @Cypher Indeed, that is true :) It's pretty subjective, like all opinions, so I can not give any guarantees, other than saying that it worked well for me.

Comment: yeah David, I think I'm going to check out the book, if anything it should point me in the right direction (I can manage with there being difference between 3.1 and 4.0). Thanks!:)